# AngularJS - How to wait for Google token before ajax call

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure how use a promise to wait for google to return a id_token. I would then make an ajax request using that token. Currently, it just immediately performs the ajax request before it has the token.

```
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDialog']);

app.controller('directory_controller', function($scope, $q, $http, ngDialog) {
    $http({
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        url: "my_ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: "gtoken=" + id_token
    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(response);
    }),
    function(response) {
        console.log("failure");
        console.log(response);
    }
});
</script>

<div ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller='directory_controller'> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

Comment: Where `googleUser` comes from?

Comment: I believe googleUser is a global from apis.google.com/js/platform.js... This is straight out of: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in